# ORCA: meaning of numbers in ORCA.out of MOLECULAR ORBITALS for STO-3G Lithium

Tags: quantum-chemistry, basis-set

For [Lithium STO-3G](https://www.basissetexchange.org/basis/sto-3g/format/nwchem/?version=1&elements=3) basis set

```
BASIS "ao basis" PRINT
#BASIS SET: (6s,3p) -> [2s,1p]
Li    S
      0.1611957475E+02       0.1543289673E+00
      0.2936200663E+01       0.5353281423E+00
      0.7946504870E+00       0.4446345422E+00
Li    SP
      0.6362897469E+00      -0.9996722919E-01       0.1559162750E+00
      0.1478600533E+00       0.3995128261E+00       0.6076837186E+00
      0.4808867840E-01       0.7001154689E+00       0.3919573931E+00
END
```

I see the for representing Lithium wave function (Single Slater's Determitatn) I need 3 basis STO-functions (STO(1s), STO(2s) and one STO(2p)) for compilation spin-orbitals. For Lithium we have $1s^22s$-eclectronic structure, so I need compile:

\begin{align}
\chi_{1s} = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{K} C_{(1s)_j} STO_j,\\
\phi_{1s} = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{L} D_{(1s)_j} STO_j,\\
\chi_{2s} = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{M} C_{(2s)_j} STO_j.\\
\ldots.
\end{align}
(As I understand)

So, I started to calculate with ORCA Lithium atom

```
! UHF STO-3G
   
%coords
    CTyp xyz       # the type of coordinates = xyz or internal
    Charge 0       # the total charge of the molecule
    Mult 2         # the multiplicity = 2S+1
    Units Angs     # the unit of length = angs or bohrs
    coords
        Li        0.000000       0.00000        0.00000
    end
end
%output
    Print[ P_Basis ] 2
    Print[ P_MOs ] 1
end
```

and get information

```
------------------
MOLECULAR ORBITALS
------------------
                      0         1         2         3         4   
                  -2.36917  -0.18012   0.13013   0.13013   0.13013
                   1.00000   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
                  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------
  0Li  1s         0.992528 -0.276813  0.000000  0.000000 -0.000000
  0Li  2s         0.029310  1.029989 -0.000000 -0.000000  0.000000
  0Li  1pz       -0.000000  0.000000 -0.607531  0.786960 -0.107701
  0Li  1px       -0.000000  0.000000 -0.176173 -0.265720 -0.947816
  0Li  1py       -0.000000  0.000000  0.774512  0.556854 -0.300075

                      0         1         2         3         4   
                  -2.33786   0.10225   0.19092   0.19092   0.19092
                   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
                  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------
  0Li  1s         0.991218 -0.281468  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0Li  2s         0.034144  1.029840 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000
  0Li  1pz       -0.000000 -0.000000  0.170191 -0.976799  0.129992
  0Li  1px       -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.983678 -0.160587  0.081175
  0Li  1py       -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.058416 -0.141685 -0.98818
```

So, how can I determine $K$, $L$ and $M$ numbers and $C_{(1s)_j}$, $D_{(1s)_j}$, $C_{(2s)_j}$ coefitients?

Comment: I think that question hasn't gotten the attention it should have. At the time of posting [mattermodeling.se] did not exist. It does now, but the question is now too old to migrate. I would suggest to just ask it there (again) and delete it here. I am quite confident you'll find an answer there. (Finally. (I guess.))